# Generating module description with puppet-doc

Tags: puppet

I can successfully generated Puppet documentation for my modules' classes (using puppet-doc) but I would also like to include a module-level documentation (similar to http://docs.puppetlabs.com/puppet/3/reference/modules_documentation.html.) I tried to put a README.md, README.markdown, [modulename].md or [modulename].markdown at the module top-level but without success.

What is the line I missed to read on the documentation?

Answer (score 0):

Documentation at [PuppetLabs](http://projects.puppetlabs.com/projects/1/wiki/Puppet_Manifest_Documentation) suggests that README is respected, not README.md or .markdown.

Seeing as puppet doc is basically rdoc, it doesn't support typical markdown and instead expects an rdoc format, or just plain text.